# My vb class and my html file content in Visual Studio 2015 has been encrypted and destroyed

Tags: windows, visual-studio, encryption

I have worked on my project in Visual Studio about about one html file and one vb file content are encrypted after closing solution.

I have check previews version of file and Visual Studio backup directory.

Both of above are empty. and my files are coded.

My anti virus is NOD32 and it is updated recently.

[This is preview of encrypted file by Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DSGE.png)

Comment: Are the lost files stored in a version control system? What system was responsible for encrypting them?

Comment: Hmm, that file is clearly not HTML, but it does not look encrypted - there are recognisable strings in there.

Comment: That file contains strings like NTFS and ntos, its likely corrupted not encrypted.

Comment: no i worked on my file in visual studio recently.

but not corrupted. when i close normally vs and reopen it, i seems this case is happened. ):

Answer (score 0):

There is a BackUp Folder for Visual Studio 2015 in your system 
 Look Here

```
"C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Backup Files"
```

Comment: please do tell if its helped

Comment: thank you. i found a copy in above address... seems my hdd has bad-sectors... i buy another...